# intelli command + shift + / do block comment as well as opens help tab

Tags: intellij-idea

I tried both community and ultimate version and both have the same behavior. Wondering if anyone else facing the same issue.

When I press `command + shift + /` I am expecting it should make a block comment nothing else. It's doing it but along with that it also opens Help tab of the editor.

**is not it a bug?**

```
other comment command and result
command + fn + /  --> doing as expected
command + / --> inline comment and as expected
```

Comment: Have you checked your keybindings/keyboard shortcuts in settings for duplicates?

Comment: What do you mean by the help tab? What keymap do you use?

Comment: help tab in top of the IDE. I can any key combination and make it anything. the question it comes with default. how they mapped same functionality to two different functionality

Comment: Still not clear, provide a screenshot of what you call the "Help tab".

Comment: Same here on MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 1):

OS X has a system wide keyboard shortcut to open the current applications help menu. Unfortunately it conflicts with the default IntelliJ block comment shortcut when using the Mac OS X keymap.

You will need to change one of them. I personally just turn off the system wide shortcut since I have never intentionally used it.

**If you want to change the OS X shortcut**

1. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
2. Select 'App Shortcuts' in the left pane.
3. Look for 'Show help menu' under the 'All Applications' section in the right pane
4. Then either turn the shortcut off with the checkbox or change it clicking on the right side of the row.

[image: OSX System Preferences]

**If you want the change the IntelliJ shortcut**

1. Application Menu > Preferences
2. Select 'Keymap' in the list on the left.
3. Use the top right search field to search for 'block comment'
4. Right click on the 'Comment with Block Comment' row to change the shortcut.

[image]

Comment: I am actually now habituated of using `command + control` to block comment which will not open help along with commenting the code. But still it is looking some hacky way and was very much concerned at that time.